# Any good informational blogs or websites devoted to .Net developers for OAuth?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth

I need a site that does a decent walkthrough on getting one of the OAuth projects for .Net running for my own company's use.  Any pointers to documentation and related sample code would be much appreciated.  I can already find DevDefined, Magex, and DotNetOpenAuth.  I just don't find anyone writing up their own use of these projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... how's this?  It's a snippet, but it looks like it's a good sample:

http://blog.stevienova.com/2008/04/19/oauth-getting-started-with-oauth-in-c-net/

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog post on how to use DevDefined OAuth to connect to Yahoo's Fantasy Football API. This should apply to any of Yahoo's APIs as well as other public projects on OAuth 1.0.

[How to Query the Yahoo Fantasy Football API in .NET](http://blog.yeahstu.com/2011/10/04/how-to-query-the-yahoo-fantasy-football-api-in-net/)